# Order Structures on the collection of all the subfunctors of a presheaf

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a small category and $y: \mathcal{C} \to {\bf Sets}^{\mathcal{C}^{op}}$ be its Yoneda embedding. It is well-known that the family of subobjects of $y(C)$, where $C \in \mathcal{C}$, is a preorder and always contains a "maximum" subobject (i.e. the maximal sieve). It is possible to deduce some other informations? For instance, under which hypotheses the above family forms a complete lattice?

Comment: Hmm... The yoneda embedding reflects all limits, so it reflects the property of being a monomorphism, so a (iso class of) monomorphism $yA\to yX$ is a (iso class of) monomorphism $A\to X$; now, when is the poset of subobjects of every object $X$ of a category $\cal C$ a lattice? See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2327619/when-is-the-lattice-of-subobjects-a-complete-lattice). This also says that if you consider *all* the subobjects of $yX$, they always form a complete lattice (this means: the representable, and non-representable ones, together).